# Adding value 0 to existing column based on comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, number-formatting

I have a DataFrame that looks like below:

```
name price
x    ,12
y    ,9
z    10,25
```

I have to add "0" before the comma (unless there is already a number before the comma, in that case it can't be changed) so DataFrame should looks like below:

```
name price
x    0,12
y    0,9
z    10,25
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You could use df['price'].apply with a custom function. [link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are working with strings and not numbers, this does the trick for me:

```
df["price"] = df["price"].where(~df["price"].str.startswith(","), "0"+df["price"])
```

Here is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["x",",12"],["y",",3"],["z","5"],["o","1,2"]], columns=["name","price"])
print("input:", df)
df["price"] = df["price"].where(~df["price"].str.startswith(","), "0"+df["price"])
print("output:", df)
```

yields:

```
input:   name price
0    x   ,12
1    y    ,3
2    z     5
3    o   1,2
output:   name price
0    x  0,12
1    y   0,3
2    z     5
3    o   1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**  Here is a potential solution:

```
    A   B
0   1   ,2
1   2   ,02
2   3   1,3
3   4   ,9
4   5   13
5   6   12
```

and

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace(",", "0,",  regex=True)
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>4}'.format(x))
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','.'))
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(float)
```

which gives

```
    A   B
0   1   0.20
1   2   0.02
2   3   1.30
3   4   0.90
4   5   13.00
5   6   12.00
```

Comment: Note however, that the 1,3 was changed to 10,3 in your example, so there is no distinction between a leading comma and one in the center.

Comment: My bad. I have corrected it. I assume you actually want ```float```, not ```string```